# Where do I put my login logic in WPF and how do I handle it in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm currently working on an application that implements the MVVM architecture, where I am trying to do the login logic.
I have a pretty good idea of what the main responsibilities of both `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ICommand` are, and have already implemented them to all my view models that need them.
Here's a short of my code:

I have an `ApplicationViewModel.cs` that handles the main window `ApplicationView.xaml`.
The main 
window has a sidebar menu on the left, and a `<ContentControl>` that that is binded to the `CurrentViewModel` property of type `ViewModelBase` in `ApplicationViewModel.cs`.
All child view models are contained in a `List<ViewModelBase>` property. It gets its views from a `DataTemplate` with the corresponding view model, thus providing me a working navigation system.

So here's what I initially thought of doing:

In a child view model called `LoginViewModel.cs`, I thought it was logical to do the login logic, as it also handled the view itself. I wrote a model class `User.cs` with corresponding properties to the database columns. I wrote some classes that would help me get the data from the database to the application.

The view model checks for how many characters are entered and executes the `Login` once the user has entered 4 characters for the pin code, which instantiates a `User` object in `LoginViewModel.cs`

The problem here for me, is that I need the instance of the `User` to be application wide and therefore probably needs be in the `ApplicationViewModel.cs` instead.

So, from that, I have 2 questions:

- Is there a better approach to this and a better way handle the login logic?
- If the logic I already made is fine, how do I hand the instance of the `User` from the child view model `LoginViewModel.cs` to the parent view model `ApplicationViewModel.cs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; it wasn't quite natural to come towards this solution when I first started, but you actually can add some kind of 4th layer in MVVM, the Services layer (well, it's more of a pattern than an actual MVVM layer).

Services are single-instance objects that you inject into your viewmodels, and serve exactly that kind of purpose, which is holding and potentially treating data that should circulate between viewmodels.

You will need a dependency injector, a class that will bother with finding the correct service for the classes injected with it.

So you have two concepts to study:

- Services
- Inversion of control/dependency injection

I can't just give you an implementation of a dependency injector, because I personally don't have one.
I'm using a MVVM framework that provides me with one already.

It's basically used this way:

- You create an interface for each of your services; it keeps concerns separated (no coupling between service implementations and viewmodels).
- You register your service implementation by their interfaces (something like `myDependencyInjector.Register<IMyService>(typeof(MyService))` at the start of your program
- You add the desired service interfaces to the relevant viewmodels' constructors (`MyViewModel(IMyService myService)`)

Comment: After researching for a little while, your post seems to be the answer I'm seeking for. This is kind of an unnecessary ask, but can you suggest some materiale for learning this concept?

Comment: As I said, I'm using a framework that provides me with this out-of-the-box, so I can't really help you much except by directing your to the obvious [MSDN pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx). Or you can use said framework :p just know it's kinda huge, with many functionnalities, and it will take time to learn it as well: [Catel](http://catelproject.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You could implement custom authentication and authorization by creating classes that derive from the `IIdentity` and `IPrincipal` interfaces and override the application thread's default identity. Please refer to the following blog post for more information about how to do this.

**Custom authorization in WPF**: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/24/custom-authorization-in-wpf/.

You basically create an `IPrincipal` and use the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal` method to associate this principal with the `AppDomain` in your application. You can then use the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property everywhere in your application to determine whether the user is authenticated.

In the code sample, the actual authentication is done by the `AuthenticationService` class. You could for example implement this one to check the passed in credentials against a remote database. The view model uses this service to perform the authentication.